# Schedule replication overnight

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a MySQL database, where approximately 3.5 million entries are been inserted/updated daily. For some heavier data analysis I would like to create a replica.

Is it possible to schedule the replication over night? Most of the changes are being inserted/updated over the day. I found the Delayed Replication, but that is not exactly what I am searching for. I would like to collect all the changes and in the night I would like to start the replication.

I've tried a replication, but during the day it has too much impact on the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could configure replication, but then use [STOP REPLICA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stop-replica.html) during the day, so it is not processing the changes. The changes will queue up on the source instance in the binary log, and you can START REPLICA at the end of the day so they are processed overnight.

If the binary log itself is too much overhead, so you can't enable it on the source instance without impacting performance, then you can't use replication. But you could use a snapshot of the source instance, and restore it to another instance at night. I call that "another instance" instead of a replica, because you don't configure replication in this case. It's just a restored snapshot of the source.

I would use Percona XtraBackup to make the snapshot. If you use a cloud database, there is probably a snapshot feature built into the service.

Comment: The binlog is low-overhead.  If that is enough to "break the camel's back", you have a more serious melt-down coming soon.

Comment: Yes, I would not think that having binlog enabled is the culprit, but it's unclear from the OP's question. I have seen cases where the binlog overhead was the problem, and yes, that application was in serious need of sharding over multiple db servers, but the developers didn't want to.